# fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gitaccount/repo-name.git/': Operation timed out after 300017 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Tags: networking, git, github, gnutls

I am unable to do git clone from github.com from `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`, Tried all solutions from other answers.
Disabled ubuntu firewall, and am on home network, so no other firewalls.On windows everything is fine.
I am not using any proxy servers.

```
ramez@ramez-nx:~/lab$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Set SSL verify = false

```
ramez@ramez-nx:~/lab$ git config --global https.sslVerify false
```

I don't know what else to try, really stuck for days.

```
ramez@ramez-nx:~/lab$ set -x; GIT_TRACE=2 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2 GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2 GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2 GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2 GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2 git clone https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-core.git -v -v; set +x –
+ GIT_TRACE=2
+ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PACK_ACCESS=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2
+ GIT_TRACE_PACKFILE=2
+ GIT_TRACE_SETUP=2
+ GIT_TRACE_SHALLOW=2
+ git clone https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-core.git -v -v
10:03:38.851319 git.c:444               trace: built-in: git clone https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-core.git -v -v
Cloning into 'sqlectron-core'...
10:03:38.856462 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-core.git
10:03:38.863159 http.c:756              == Info: Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
10:03:48.877543 http.c:756              == Info:   Trying 140.82.118.3:443...
10:03:48.877579 http.c:756              == Info: TCP_NODELAY set
10:03:49.004993 http.c:756              == Info: Connected to github.com (140.82.118.3) port 443 (#0)
10:03:49.029753 http.c:756              == Info: found 383 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
10:03:49.029809 http.c:756              == Info: ALPN, offering h2
10:03:49.029814 http.c:756              == Info: ALPN, offering http/1.1
10:08:13.018780 http.c:756              == Info: gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
10:08:13.018844 http.c:756              == Info: Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-core.git/': gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
10:08:13.028404 trace.c:487             performance: 274.177112071 s: git command: git clone https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-core.git -v -v
+ set +x –



ramez@ramez-nx:~/lab$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried git clone on another Ubuntu-**"20.04.1 LTS"** live boot, and the issue is present there also. Apparently this is an issue with "20.04.1 LTS" version.

Now I am using "Ubuntu **18.04 lts**", and everything is fine, life is nice n' dandy, full of sunshine... I'm out of my depression and getting back to life again.